# Share auth sessions across sub domains with multiple Laravel 5 project

Tags: php, laravel-5

Current system:

- Have two Laravel project: 5.2 and 5.3
- Using sub domain on local: control.foo-bar.dev (Laravel 5.2) and service.foo-bar.dev (Laravel 5.3)

.ENV setting:

`APP_KEY=base64:tRpczdAlZ3jZ5VbP4sBU6BJcltftB5pBFpOuHbh/pq4=`

`SESSION_DRIVER=cookie`

`SESSION_DOMAIN=foo-bar.dev`

config/app.php setting:

`'cookie' => 'laravel_session'`

Now I can login from Laravel 5.2 and can use that cookies for Laravel 5.3 but can't opposite.

I had try to change `SESSION_DRIVER=cookie` => `database` but get same result.

Answer (score 3):

With this situation, I am pretty sure you have to prepend the dot on your cookie domain. eg:

`SESSION_DOMAIN=.foo-bar.dev`

Give it a go, see if it works.

**Edit:** Also, my 5.2 has the session cookie domain as `null` so make sure it is set to `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),` in your config/session.php

Comment: I already set it. But this isn't problems.
Problems come from laravel version.